# Combine multiple rows into one MySQL Join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I couldn't think of a better way to ask this question, but here goes:

I have 2 tables.  The first is a table of items for label printing jobs. We'll call it `pj_items` The columns are simply: `job_id, part_num and qty`

The second table is a list of finishes called `PartFinishes` on parts with just 2 columns of: `PartNumber and FinishId`

When I want to retrieve information for the label printer I use:

`select pj_items.part_num, pj_items.qty, PartFinishes.FinishId from pj_items`

`join PartFinishes on PartFinishes.PartNumber = pj_items.part_num`

`where job_id = 1`

This query works fine and gives me the right result when each part has only one finish.  The problem is when there are 2 or more finishes on a part.

For example: The part `99401326` has 2 finishes. On my `pj_items` table I have one row for that part so I can print one label. When I use this query it returns 2 rows for that part each with a different `FinishId` Unfortunately that would result in 2 labels printed.  I need both of those finishes on one row since I only want one label printed with both `FinishId`'s present.

I had a similar query which returned the finishes as new columns (`f1,f2,f3`) But it would still return 2 rows in the given example with `f1` defined in the first row and `f1` as null in the second row and `f2` being defined in the second.

How can I get that into one row?

Hopefully that makes sense, anyone have any suggestions?

If you need anymore info, let me know.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The `pj_items` table may have duplicate entries and I need to preserve those as separate rows.  I just need to have all the finishes for each part in one row with its respective part.

**Example**

Here is an example of the pj_items table:

[image: pj_items table]

Here is the relevant information from the `PartFinishes` table:

[image: PartFinishes table]

And here is the result using the original query:

[image: results]

What I need in the result is the two rows of `99401326` are one with both of the finishes in that row, while maintaining the 2 seperate rows for the `99401077` since I want 2 labels of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT to combine all finish ID's for a given part into one column.

```
SELECT pj_items.part_num, 
       pj_items.qty, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(PartFinishes.FinishId) as FinishIds
FROM pj_items
JOIN PartFinishes 
  ON PartFinishes.PartNumber = pj_items.part_num
WHERE job_id = 1
GROUP BY PartFinishes.PartNumber
```

@comment:
However if you want to keep rows from pj_items separated you will need to join PartFinishes already grouped by PartNumber:

```
SELECT pj_items.part_num, 
   pj_items.qty, 
   FinishesGrouped.FinishIds
FROM pj_items
JOIN 
  ( SELECT PartNumber, GROUP_CONCAT(FinishId) as FinishIds
    FROM PartFinishes
    GROUP BY PartNumber ) FinishesGrouped
ON
  pj_items.part_num = FinishesGrouped.PartNumber
```

Comment: That works.  The problem then is if I want to print multiple labels of  one part, I'd have 2 or 3 rows in the pj_items table of the same part.  Those rows get combined into one with the same finish multiple times in the FinishIds column.  I should probably add more specifics to my question.  Thanks for the answer though!